# `ModuleNotFoundError` in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter

My notebook and modules are placed like below.

```
my_directory
  modules  # This is just a directory, not a module
    my_module_1.py
    my_module_2.py
  my_notebook.ipynb
```

`my_module_1.py` is imported in `my_module_2.py`, and `my_module_2.py` is imported in `my_notebook.ipynb` like below.

```
# in `my_module_2.py`
import my_module_1 as something
```

```
# in `my_notebook.ipynb`
import modules.my_module_2 as something
from modules.my_module_2 import my_function
```

If I run `my_module_2.py` only, then it works correctly. However, if I run the code in `my_notebook.ipynb`, then `ModuleNotFoundError` is raised like below.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import modules.my_module_2 as something

File ~\my_directory\modules\my_module_2.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 import my_module_1 as something

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_module_1'
```

The notebook works if I change `my_module_2.py` like below, but then `my_module_2.py` doesn't work if I run it only...

```
# in `my_module_2.py`
import modules.my_module_1.py import something
```

Is there anything I can do to make both the module and the notebook work without changing the structure of the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want your project top folder `my_directory` path to be searchable by python. you need the absolute path to that folder to be either

1. on your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable
2. your current working directory when invoking `python modules/my_module_1.py`
3. your "project directory" for your IDE (like pycharm and spyder and vscode). they secretly add it to your `PYTHONPATH` or make it your working directory and call `python modules/my_module_1.py` when you hit run.
4. create a minimal `setup.py` and install the package in editable mode `pip install -e .` to be added to python's search paths.

any of those methods will allow you to write

```
import modules.my_module_1 as something
import modules.my_module_2 as something_else
```

in your notebook and in `my_module_1.py` and in any other project, and they will all resolve correctly.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
Is there any way without changing `my_module_2.py`?

Comment: @Prown you could add both `my_directory` and `modules` to your `PYTHONPATH`, and both methods will work, but that's not a sane way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much!